# How to retrieve data from database on dropdownlist index changed event without refreshing web page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have a two dropdownlists in my project, `ddFtherEmployeeNumber` and `ddFatherName`. On `ddFatherEmployeeNumber selectedIndexChange` event, I want data to load into `ddEmployeeFatherName` from the database.

I have done that and it works perfectly fine. But there is a problem that after each iteration on `indexchange` event, it refreshes the page, and I don't like that. I have searched online but couldn't find a better solution.

That's why I came here and post my question. A lot of people says that you have to do it with jQuery Ajax and some also mentioned about `UpdatePanel`. But I don't understand anything about jQuery. So folks, please help me out. Either through `UpdatePanel` or through jQuery Ajax.

Here is my `.aspx` page

```html
<div class="form-group row">
                            <!--Row two-->
                            <div class="col-md-8 forLabels">
                                <div class="col-md-6"></div>
                                <asp:Label ID="EmpFatherEmployeeNo" for="EmpFatherEmployeeNo" runat="server" Visible="True">Father Employee Number*</asp:Label>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddFatherEmployeeNumber" runat="server" CssClass="input-sm form-control custom" AutoPostBack="True" DataTextField="EmployeeNo" DataValueField="Id" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddFatherEmployeeNumber_SelectedIndexChanged" ClientIDMode="Static" AppendDataBoundItems="true"></asp:DropDownList>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 forLabels">
                                <asp:Label ID="EmpFatherName" for="EmpFatherName" runat="server">Father Name</asp:Label>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddEmployeeFatherName" runat="server" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id" CssClass="input-sm form-control"></asp:DropDownList>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Here is my `ddFatherEmployeeNumber_SelectedIndexChanged`

```
 protected void ddFatherEmployeeNumber_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@EmployeeNo", ddFatherEmployeeNumber.SelectedItem.Text);
            DataSet DS = GetData("spGetFatherNameByFatherEmployeeNumber", param);
            ddEmployeeFatherName.DataSource = DS;
            ddEmployeeFatherName.DataBind();
    }
```

This is my `GetData` Method

```
private DataSet GetData(string SPName, SqlParameter SPParameter)
    {
        DataSet DS = new DataSet();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Base.GetConnection))
        {

            SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(SPName, con);
            ad.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            if (SPParameter != null)
            {
                ad.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(SPParameter);
            }
            ad.Fill(DS);
        }
        return DS;
    }
```

The purpose of this is that, I have `IsValidated()` Method which is

```
private bool IsValidated()
    {
        if (tbEmployeeName.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            tbEmployeeName.BorderColor = Color.Red;
            ShowNotification("Error: Name is required!", WarningType.Danger);
            tbEmployeeName.Focus();
            return false;
        }
        if (tbEmployeeApplicationNo.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            tbEmployeeName.BorderColor = Color.Transparent;
            tbEmployeeApplicationNo.BorderColor = Color.Red;
            ShowNotification("Error: Application Number is Required!", WarningType.Danger);
            tbEmployeeApplicationNo.Focus();
            return false;
        }
    return true;
    }
```

Now when i don't enter the `Name` or `ApplicationNo` and press on `Add` button, it shows me a `Message` that it is required. Here program works fine, but for the second time when i don't enter anything in the required fields, it shows a message again but this time, the dropdownlist `ddFatherEmployeeNo` fails to load data. i don't understand why its loosing its datasource after couple of post back operations. here are the pictures for clear understanding. For the first time it loads record perfectly here is the picture
[image]

But when `IsValidated()` function gives me a message of `Name is required or something like that`, then `ddFatherEmployeeNo` dropdownlist loses its `datasource`. Here is the picture 
[image]

So my main question is that, How to prevent the page from refreshing on `_SelectedIndexChanged` event and what to do to stop this `Error` that i am facing.`Dropdownlist loses its DataSource after postback`. 
Here is my `Page_Load` Event code

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ddFatherEmployeeNumber.DataSource = GetData("spGetFatherEmployeeNumber", null);
            ddFatherEmployeeNumber.DataBind();
            ddFatherEmployeeNumber.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Father Employee No", "0"));
        } 
    }
```

**UPDATE:** I have a `script` that select data. here it is

```js
 <%--Code for Selecting Dropdown List Item--%>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#ddFatherEmployeeNumber").select2({
                placeholder: "Select an option",
                allowClear: true
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I think it has something to do with the postback.

Comment: You can use Cascading dropdownlist or update panel

Answer (score 2):

Since you have mentioned in your question that you do not know what jquery or ajax is, I am going to write a small answer explaining those two (even though searching for it online will provide you with 1000's of explanations!)

[Jquery](https://jquery.com) is a javascript library that helps you write cross-browser/cross-platform javascript without worrying about ensuring that you are writing JS code to cater to all browsers. It became famous and still widely used when the browsers weren't heavily using standard JS implementations (especially for DOM manipulations, event handling, and AJAX.

With jquery, you can manipulate the DOM rather easily (Document Object Model), which is basically everything in your browser's window (the Document itself, the body tags and all other tags within your document). When I say manipulate, it means you can programmatically add new tags, alter tags, change the contents of tags, search for certain tags in a body and then action upon them (change their CSS), which means being able to change a color of a DIV, border, animations etc.

What you can also do is AJAX stuff. What is AJAX you ask.

[AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) is short for Aynchronous Javascript and XML. In a nutshell, it helps your web-page (and more specifically the javascript in your web-page) to make calls to a backend server (whether it is ASP.NET, Python, PHP or anything on the backend) to push or pull data, without having to reload the page. And hence the name asynchronous. Because, you can possibly make multiple AJAX calls to multiple backends and your web-page would not need to refresh. The browser will automagically take care of receiving those data back from the backend and calling functions that will handle the responses.

Those functions (javascript functions) can then using the data that came back, make changes to the DOM (whether it be upgrading a drop-down list), changing the color of something, adding a notification badge or anything that your imagination can allow you to imagine.

I would strongly suggest you start by at least looking at an easy resource that covers jquery and ajax such as [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp) even though some would suggest it is not the best resource out there or not the most 'security-conscious' resource. It does a great job of at least getting you a head-start when you are completely clueless about a certain topic.

Hope my answer helps.

Just to help you out, I am going write some code that combines a PHP backend, jquery and AJAX calls. This is just an example from a project I am working on ...

```
 $('#floor').change(function() { //A dropdown list...

    //console.log("was floor triggered");
    $('#currentTenants').html(""); //jquery at work... 
    $('#employeeDetailsForm').hide();
    $('#tenantSummaryBar').css('background-color','rgba(255,255,255,1)'); //jquery adding new css to a DOM element
    $('#tenantCount').html("");

    var floorID = $(this).val(); //preparing my JSON object.. 

    $.post(
        '<?php echo $this->createUrl("EmployeeMovements/getRoomsFromFloorID"); ?>', //the backend which will asynchronously, without page refresh, receive the floor ID..
        {data: floorID}, //telling AJAX what to send.. in a POST request, but asynchronously..almost like a FORM submit button, but without the refresh.
        function(data) // the function that will be called WHEN the backend replies to us.. so your other JS can keep running... and when the browser is notified .. it'll come here to call this function.
        {
            var result = JSON.parse(data); //I receive the data in a JSON format (it could be XML), and I'm asking for JS to help parse it.
            var newOptions = "";

            for(i in result) //iterating through the result..
            {
                newOptions += "<option value='" + result[i]['roomID'] + "'>" + result[i]['roomCode'] + "</option>"; //preparing new 'options for a dropdown list based on the server's response
            }

            $('#room').html(newOptions); //using jquery to update yet another drop down list..
```

The backend code is even more simpler:

```
public function actiongetRoomsFromFloorID()
{
    if(isset($_POST['data'])) //checking if there is POST data
    {
        $rooms = Rooms::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('floorID'=>$_POST['data'])); //using my frameworks's ORM to get my data based on what the FRONT END (AJAX query asked me..)

        print json_encode($rooms); //sending back the data by just echoing back the response, and encoding in JSON format... 
    }

}
```

Comment: Thankyou for the detailed information. Maybe i asked in a question that what is Jquery or AJAZ, but i didn't mean that i don't know these server side technologies. My main motive was that i don't know how to fetch data from database through Jquery AJAX. Anyhow i give you +1 for the information. Thanks.

Comment: That wasn't a small answer tho

Comment: @Af'faq, thanks :) I thought maybe you are new to them and therefore I felt I could benefit you

Answer (score 0):

In your page add a `ScriptManager` and wrap your controls inside `UpdatePanel` like below. Then it will not refresh your page on event change.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
       <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <!--Row two-->
            <div class="col-md-8 forLabels">
                <div class="col-md-6"></div>
                <asp:Label ID="EmpFatherEmployeeNo" for="EmpFatherEmployeeNo" runat="server" Visible="True">Father Employee Number*</asp:Label>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddFatherEmployeeNumber" runat="server" CssClass="input-sm form-control custom" AutoPostBack="True" DataTextField="EmployeeNo" DataValueField="Id" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddFatherEmployeeNumber_SelectedIndexChanged" ClientIDMode="Static" AppendDataBoundItems="true"></asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 forLabels">
                <asp:Label ID="EmpFatherName" for="EmpFatherName" runat="server">Father Name</asp:Label>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddEmployeeFatherName" runat="server" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id" CssClass="input-sm form-control"></asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
        </div>
       </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

for more details follow the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb399001(v=vs.140))

Comment: Note that an UpdatePanel still refreshes the whole page. But you don't see it since only the part that has changed is updated in the UI.

Comment: Yeah i have already done that, but there is problem with dropdownlist datasource, it loses its source after couple of post backs. or if i can explain it as, when i click on button, without putting anything in required fields, it prevent record from saving into databse. Now for the second time if i do that again, then dropdownlist lost its datasource. by lost means, there is nothing showing in dropdownlist. It pops up a message that no records found. that is my whole problem brother. why the dropdownlist not showing records?

Comment: @VDWWD But MSDN says it `UpdatePanel remove the requirement to refresh the whole page with each postback`. It does a partial-page update in the UI.

Comment: Yes, the page is not refreshed. But all the code is still running in page_load like it was a "normal" page refresh.

Comment: For the first time it will load data on load event after that it will not because of `!IsPostBack` function. So i think its not the problem here.